# Angular proxy not working when i call my rest service

Tags: angular

I want ta call my rest api with proxy because of Cors error. But my proxy doesn't work any way. I took http://localhost:4200/api/users/login 401 (Unauthorized) error.

This is my proxy.config.json file.

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://xxx.herokuapp.com",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

This is options which i add in angular.js;

```
"options": {
            "browserTarget": "study-buddy:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.config.json"
          },
```

Also i added --proxy-config src/proxy.config.json parameter. "start": "ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.config.json"

I call my service like this;

```
return this.http.post<LoginResponseData>('/api/users/login', {
      user: {email: email, password: password}
    }).pipe(catchError(LoginService.handleError), tap(response => {
      return this.handleAuth(response.user.id, response.user.email, response.user.bio, response.user.image,
        response.user._token, response.user.firstName, response.user.lastName)
    }))
```

My Log;

```
alibugrat@Alis-MacBook-Air study-buddy % npm start

> study-buddy@0.0.1 start
> ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.config.json

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size
vendor.js             | vendor        |   2.34 MB | 
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 333.89 kB | 
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 299.91 kB | 
main.js               | main          |  51.19 kB | 
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.52 kB | 

                      | Initial Total |   3.01 MB

Build at: 2022-02-21T20:54:35.982Z - Hash: 45c414a1114da13d - Time: 1667ms

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


✔ Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Is your login endpoint `https://xxx.herokuapp.com/users/login`? if it has `/api`, you'll need to remove the pathRewrite

Comment: No https://xxx.herokuapp.com/users/login is my endpoint. I need to keep pathRewrite. Am i wrong?

Comment: In that case, it's correct to keep pathRewrite. You have the debug logLevel enabled, do you get anything in the console indicating that it's setting up the proxy?... Maybe you can provide redacted snippet of your console logs?

Comment: Actually i don't receive any log about proxy on my console. I added my log in the question. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had to delete the origin header from the request. I changed my proxy.config.json to proxy.config.js and configured it like this;

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://xxx.herokuapp.com",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "onProxyReq": function(pr, req, res) {
      pr.removeHeader('Origin');
    }
  }
};

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;.removeHeader('Origin');
    }
```

But still i don't receive any log. :(